# Is there a way to reverse two lines in a text file for creating a hash table?

Tags: powershell

I have a whitelist table (txt file) formatted with comment and IP address pairs like so:

```
comment about 1.2.3.4
1.2.3.4
comment about 5.6.7.8
5.6.7.8
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to get the content from the text file and create a hash table of the pairs with the IP address being the key/name and the comment being the value (since I don't care about the comment being unique).

I've figured out how to create a hash table with the comment as the key and the IP as the value using a dummy whitelist with no duplicates. But my actual whitelist has a ton of duplicate comments. Otherwise, I'd just do that and then reverse the hash. I need to pair the lines up like below before I create the hash. I'm just stuck on how to flip the comment and IP.

```
Get-Content $whitelist -ReadCount 2 | ForEach-Object{($_ | Where{![String]::IsNullorEmpty($_)}) -Join "="} > $joinedTable

$hash = Get-Content -Path $joinedTable -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Comment: Simply reverse the order of the two lines by using an index => `Get-Content $whitelist -ReadCount 2 | ForEach-Object{($_ | Where{![String]::IsNullorEmpty($_)})[1,0] -Join "="} > $joinedTable`

Comment: @LotPings Wow. I had no idea it worked that way. That solved my problem. Thanks for the answer and for fixing my question format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make an answer from my comment,

- which also saves the intermediate file $joinedtable.
- reversing the order of the input line pairs by using an index `[1,0]`

```
$whitelist = '.\whitelist.txt'

$hash = Get-Content $whitelist -ReadCount 2 | ForEach-Object{
    ($_ | Where{![String]::IsNullorEmpty($_)})[1,0] -Join "="
   } | ConvertFrom-StringData
$hash
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want:

```
$whitelist = 'PATH TO THE WHITELIST.TXT FILE'

# read the whitelist.txt file as string array and skip empty or whitespace-only lines
$data      = @(Get-Content $whitelist) -match '\S'
$whiteHash = @{}
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $data.Count -1; $i += 2){
    $key = $data[$i + 1].Trim()
    $whiteHash[$key] = $data[$i].Trim()
}

$whiteHash
```

Output

> ```
> Name                           Value                                                                                                               
> ----                           -----                                                                                                               
> 1.2.3.4                        comment about 1.2.3.4                                                                                               
> 5.6.7.8                        comment about 5.6.7.8
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use convertfrom-string with a pattern, like this:

```
$pattern=@"
{Comment*:A comment 1}
{IP:IP1}
{Comment*:A other comment 2}
{IP:IP2}
"@

Get-Content "c:\temp\test.txt" | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $pattern
```